# Cast all columns from StringType to DoubleType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This process is quite long and I wanted to know if I can reduce it to one line

[image]

I'd like to cast all the column's from string to double.

Comment: How did you define `df`'s schema to begin with? Also, that already is "one line"

Comment: It's an assignment and all the columns are deliberately left as strings. I'm trying to cast them as double and then to drop null values and replace them with an average of the column. These are dimensions of a diamond so I felt that it's best to replace the null values with the mean. By one line, I meant a more convenient way which I found below, list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehension` in python.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
new_df1=df.select([col(c).cast("double") for c in df.columns])
```